# What is the FakeItEasy equivalent of the Moq VerifyNoOtherCalls() method

Tags: c#, moq, fakeiteasy

I'm currently a Moq user and I'm researching other mocking frameworks.

When unit testing I frequently call _mock.VerifyNoOtherCalls() so I can be certain there are no unexpected interactions beyond the ones that I have already verified.

I've searched the FakeItEasy docs and cannot find the equivalent option in their framework.  Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Strict fakes**

FakeItEasy supports [strict fakes](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/strict-fakes/) (similar to strict mocks in Moq):

```
var foo = A.Fake<IFoo>(x => x.Strict());
```

This will fail the moment an unexpected call is made.

**Semi-strict fakes**

It is also possible to configure [all calls directly](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-a-call-to-configure/#specifying-a-call-to-any-method-or-property):

```
A.CallTo(fakeShop).Throws(new Exception());
```

and combine this with [specifying different behaviors for successive calls](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changing-behavior-between-calls/#specifying-different-behaviors-for-successive-calls), however in this case, there's no benefit to doing so over using a strict fake, as a strict fake will give better messages when unconfigured methods are called. So if you want to configure some methods to be called a limited number of times, you could

```
var fakeShop = A.Fake<IShop>(options => options.Strict());
A.CallTo(() => fakeShop.GetTopSellingCandy()).Returns(lollipop).Once();
A.CallTo(() => fakeShop.Address).Returns("123 Fake Street").Once();
```

`fakeShop.GetTopSellingCandy()` and `fakeShop.Address` can be called once, the second time it will fail.

**Arbitrary checks**

If you want to check if no calls are made at arbitrary points in the test:

```
A.CallTo(fakeShop).MustNotHaveHappened();
```

It might be better to filter out some of the methods that can be executed while debugging:

```
A.CallTo(a)
 .Where(call => call.Method.Name != "ToString")
 .MustNotHaveHappened();
```

You don't want a failing test because you hovered over the variable.

Comment: Nice answer, Jeroen. There were a few minor problems with your untried code, so I amended (with my own untried code).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't entirely sure my example was correct. This looks better!

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer.  I had hoped that there would be a simple equivalent.  I guess Moq stays on top for now as our framework of choice.