# How to verify that there was no interaction with dependency in a test

Tags: c#, mocking, xunit, fakeiteasy

I want my test to verify that there was no interaction with a dependency not just individual method or property. Is there a way to do that easily?

Found answer here: 
[What is the FakeItEasy equivalent of the Moq VerifyNoOtherCalls() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006106/what-is-the-fakeiteasy-equivalent-of-the-moq-verifynoothercalls-method)

Comment: Use `null` for the dependency?

Comment: @GabrielNegut: That would work if there is no null check in method.

Comment: That´s why we assume questions to include some code showing what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck.

Comment: Mock the whole dependency?

Comment: nunit has `VerifyNoOtherCalls`, which would do what you want. I'm not sure about xunit

Comment: @RobinBennett Thanks, your comment led me to find answer on SO :)

Comment: @RobinBennett `VerifyNoOtherCalls` is a Moq method, it has nothing to do with nunit ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With FakeItEasy you can create a [strict mock](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/strict-fakes/) for your dependency and not define any methods/properties.

```
var foo = A.Fake<IFoo>(x => x.Strict());
```

Any attempts to access `foo` members will result in an `ExpectationException`.

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel's answer is fine. Another option, if you prefer to check explicitly, it this:

```
A.CallTo(theDependency).MustNotHaveHappened();
```